# Excel creating tables which use dates

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I have a table which has dates but and each date has a corresponding cell which has a number of sales. The dates are not in order but some dates are missing and many dates are repeated. How can i find the total sales per day and then group it by sales per week.

Example:

```
1/2/2015     7
1/2/2015     2
1/3/2015     1
....
```

What I want is total bookings on 1/2/2015 is 9 and so on

Comment: And I want a guitar! Or a shoe! Either way, there's a way to ask, and I also suggest you show what you've tried :)

Comment: I do not know how to start

Comment: I think we broke dave.

Comment: Reading between the lines...I think Dave was suggesting the OP read **[ask]**.

Answer (score 1):

This should get you going

A solution is to use a `SUMIF`

```
=SUMIF(A:A,A1,B:B)
```

Assuming A1 is the first entry for 1/2/2015

Or

```
=SUMIF(A:A,"1/2/2015",B:B)
```

Comment: I tried this and it gave me #name?

Comment: Are the dates in column A? And the number of sales in B @user2285166

Comment: @Dave i think table filters and slicers would be helpful tools.

Comment: @iSR5 please add as an answer then :)